# codeigniter : using flash data but no new page load?

Tags: codeigniter, session

Usually, I just set a $feedback var or array and then check for that to display in my views.

However, it occurred to me I should perhaps use flashdata instead.

The problem is sometimes - for say an edit record form, I may simply want to reload the form and display feedback - not redirect. when i use flashdata, it shows but then it shows on the next request as well.

What would be the best practice to use here?

Comment: can you summarize what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.

u use hidden field for that

Answer (score 0):

I would use the validation errors from the Form validation class and load those directly to the view in its 2nd argument.

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p>', '</p>');
$content_data = array();

if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
    $content_data['errors'] = validation_errors();
}

$this->load->view('output_page', $content_data);
```

Then check in your view whether $errors isset.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$data['message'] = 'some message you want to see on the form';
$this->load->view('yourView', $data);
```

View:

```
if (isset ($message)) : echo $message; endif;
...
```